# Ubuntu is not booting after installation

Tags: boot

My laptop is Dell 5558. I deleted Window 10. And now I have only installedUbuntu 16.04 in my hard drive, but it's not booting. After restarting, the screen came up "no boot device found, press any key to restart the machine".

GParted of drive is:

[image: GParted image]

I also used boot-repair tool but still same issue, the result address is "http://paste2.org/AFV86atz".

Comment: Your link to the pastebin doesn't work.

Comment: so what i should  do? does i have to run again boot-repair or is there any other problem?

Comment: my  bios setting is legacy and secure boot is disabled

Comment: Update the link please.

Comment: http://paste2.org/AFV86atz

Answer (score 2):

Almost everything is wrong on this partition scheme.  I see an ext4 partition with no mount point, a linux-swap partition using 59.65 GB ??? and there is no boot flag anywhere, therefore there is no active partition which the system can boot from.  This scheme is definitely created manually and it's not going to work.

Since you do not want to use any other operating system on your computer, the easiest way to make it work is to re-install Ubuntu using the installer's preconfigured partition scheme.  Just select the option that erases everything and installs Ubuntu from scratch.

You can refer to this page: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) if you want to partition your disks manually.

Comment: but i want to keep my data from other two partitions (IT, Entertainment)

Comment: Then you must re-install making correct manual partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Well , Manual partitions to give are as follows, Note its an example :

```
Mount Point    | Disk_Space(GB) | Format | Orientation
EFI Boot Part      512 MB                    At the Beginning
  /                100             ext4      At the Beginning 
  Swap             8               Swap      End of the space
  /tmp             10              ext4      End of the space
  /home            <As u like>     ext4      At the Beginning
```

And for IT and Entertainment space : Leave it as *do not use the partitions*

Boot loader to install : Select **sda**

After successfull installation better check in bios that you have enabled Legacy Mode for Boot rather than UEFI.Thats it.

*Note: Partitions given above is only for reference.*

Comment: still same.   my mail address is "zain5545436@gmail.com" plz contact me